# Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT caused from systemSound

Tags: ios, sigabrt

Hey I am very new to programming in x-code and I have been following geeky lemon's tutorial, and I wanted to add sound into my project. I am trying to create a simple piano application. I have followed every step correctly, and my code was exactly same as their although when I ran the program, the iphone simulator froze at black screen and opened xcode with

Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT in

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }T}
```

In the console the error was:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
*** First throw call stack:

My code is:
.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    SystemSoundID soundID;
}
- (IBAction)c1Press:(id)sender;
@end
```

.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Resource/Audio/keys/C1" ofType:@"MP3"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) buttonURL, &soundID);

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)c1Press:(id)sender {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
@end
```

I have done some research on this, and one answer was that the bundle was not in properly or something like that, but I checked in my build Phases and all my resources are all there and none are red.

Comment: The error is quite clear. You are passing `nil` when creating an `NSURL` object. Your call to `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Resource/Audio/keys/C1" ofType:@"MP3"]` is not working.

Comment: So how will I be able to fix that?